# Can someone help me interpret this code for an Endless Page Script?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I would like to make multiple endless pages using this script, -however I can only seem to create two pages. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
var counter = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && counter < 4) {
    appendData();
  }
});

function appendData() {
  var html = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    html += '';

  }
  if (counter < 1)
    $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-10';?>');
  counter++;
  if (counter == 3)
    $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-2';?>');
  counter++;

}
```

Comment: First time 0.  Append GNC-10.  Becomes 1.  Becomes 2.  Second time 2.  Becomes 3.  Append GNC-2.  Becomes 4.  Once it becomes 4 or more, neither of the appends will ever happen again.

Comment: Thanks! So how would I add an addition line, would it be like this?

Comment: }
        if(counter < 1)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-1';?>');
        counter++;
if(counter > 2)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-10';?>');
        counter++;
        if(counter == 3)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-2';?>');
        counter++;

    }

Comment: Please edit your question with any code, rather than putting it in the comments.  It's very hard to read.

Comment: whoops! Sorry about that

Comment: The PHP `include_once` code is executed just once, when the page is loaded, not every time `appendData()` is called. You need to use AJAX to go back to the server every time.

Comment: is there a way to do it without using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                                              var counter=0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && counter < 4) {
            appendData();
        }
    });
    function appendData() {
        var html = '';
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            html += '';

        }
        if(counter < 1)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-10.php';?>');
        counter++;
        if(counter > 2)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-1.php';?>');
        counter++;
        if(counter == 3)
        $('#myScroll').append('<? include_once 'GNC-2';?>');
        counter++;

         }
```